# Looking for a 14"x20" high quality furnace filter

Tags: air-filter, air

With increasing dust, I'm looking for a good quality furnace air filter.  This lead my search to the following:

- Honeywell 14 x 20 x 1 Elite Allergen (FPR 10)
- Filtrete MPR 2800 (MERV 14)

My issue is that I can't seem to find one or similar in Canada for my online searches.  Just need a bit of assistance in locating these please.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic probably why the down vote and votes to close myself included in that group. Read up on changing your filter density prior to jumping to a merv14 that may be well beyond your systems capabilities creating enough restrictions to trigger low flow alarms and over temp safety faults. Going bigger in this case can cause many more problems than this but those are the big ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you some perspective on dust in your house. All the dust in your house can not be removed by a furnace filter and here is why. Only a small % of the air in your home will move through the furnace and be cleaned by the filter. For example, in my home I have an electronic air cleaner with a pre-filter and and an after filter plus I had a second pre-filter installed ahead of the air cleaner and I run my furnace fan 24/7. My family had an allergy to dust and pollen which is the reason for my attempt to remove all the dust.  My wife still complains about the amount of dust in our home. Adding a better furnace filter may yield a little less dust but it will not remove it all and you will still get dust on every horizontal surface.

I searched for a 14X20X1" filter and came up with a few choices. One choice was from "filterbuy.com" for a merv13 at 4 for $43.00 for a 4 pack plus there were others to choose from like "allfilters.com". Just remember, you can filter some of the air but not all of it. Going to a high merv filter may result in not enough air flow through your furnace which could be detrimental to it and cause operating problems.  As a last thought, I was told many many years ago, that an electronic air cleaner would remove or kill bacteria and even some viruses. I do not know if that is true but since that time I have always had an electronic air cleaner in all my homes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great thank you.  Since posting, I have read up on the terminology and what I should be looking for.  These sources are also useful.